# jQuery : selector targetting a dynamic attribute not working

Tags: jquery, dynamic, selector, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to create a Fanorona game.
http://canapin.com/web/fanorona

One of my jQuery selector doesn't work as intended.

After moving a blue stone by clicking it then clicking on a green space, the active player (var activePlayer) changes from "blue" to "red".

```
    $("#board").on("click", "[data-color='"+activePlayer+"']", function(){
    console.log(activePlayer);
    console.log($(this).attr("data-color"));
```

When the active played is "red" and I click on a red stone (data-color="red"), it does nothing. when I click on a blue stone, the first console.log displays "red", but the second one displays "blue", which puzzles me because my selector uses the activePlayer variable which contains "red".

Any idea ?
Here is the full js code if it can help : http://pastebin.com/7UYks2Z1

Fanorona rules : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanorona

Comment: Just bind on `data-color` if you can get what you want from the attribute value. Here the binding is executed once only so the value used would be the value of `activePlayer` at the time that code is run. Remember you also have an `activePlayer` class which you may be able to use. And to update the variable a simple `activePlayer = activePlayer === "red" ? "blue" : "red";` would do over a `switch()`. Also noticed for some reason your `colors` array contain the `green` colour.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The variable "colors" isn't and won't be used, I should have deleted this. Regarding my actual issue, I'm not sure to understand what you mean by binding on data-color. Can you explain a little bit more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're always binding on `data-color=blue` because the variable `activePlayer` is 'blue' when the script starts.

You can solve it by binding an event to both cases.
Like this:

```
$("#board").on("click", "[data-color='red']", function(){
        activeStone["x"] = $(this).attr("data-x");
        activeStone["y"] = $(this).attr("data-y");
        checkPossibleMoves(activeStone["x"],activeStone["y"], "red");
    });

     $("#board").on("click", "[data-color='blue']", function(){
        activeStone["x"] = $(this).attr("data-x");
        activeStone["y"] = $(this).attr("data-y");
        checkPossibleMoves(activeStone["x"],activeStone["y"], "blue");
    });
```

An alternative would be binding without a `data-color` attribute and retrieving it in your callback.

Comment: I choose the alternative you suggested and it works perfectly, thanks :)